# What has the RIAA(/MPAA/BSA) done in re the recent surge in music piracy due to coronavirus?

Tags: history, copyright, record-labels

From torrentfreak.com: [Coronavirus Lockdown Boosts Interest in Pirate Sites and Services](https://torrentfreak.com/coronavirus-lockdown-boosts-interest-in-pirate-sites-and-services-200316/)

From nbcchicago.com: [More People Are Pirating Movies During the Coronavirus Lockdown](https://www.nbcchicago.com/entertainment/entertainment-news/more-people-are-pirating-movies-during-the-coronavirus-lockdown/2262721/)

Question: So what's the RIAA (/MPAA/BSA/FBI) response to this?

Explanation: Just wondering if they're responding with more or less stuff than before given these: see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liydx.jpg), [here](http://rebloggy.com/post/gif-signs-the-simpsons-simpsons-best-of-places-season-25-steal-this-episode/74869443005), [here](https://www.hackread.com/the-pirate-bay-and-anti-piracy-enforcement-theme-rock-at-the-simpsons/), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw1df.png), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFamX.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH3dG.png).

Related:

- https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/is-downloading-youtube-videos-legal
- https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/piracy-file-sharing-why-arent-songs-movies-or-books-given-for-free

---

Edit:

> Please re-open this question that was closed as opinion-based or unclear. I changed the secondary opinion question into what it was intended to be: some elaboration of the primary factual question. –
> BCLC Aug 18, 2020 at 10:10

Comment: I think there's an interesting question in here, but as stated, it comes across somewhere between "an open-ended, hypothetical" and "a rant in disguise". Can you be more clear about what you're looking for? https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Aaron well there's 'The history of songs and musicians/bands/artists/composers/songwriters/etc' and 'Use, explanation, and history of music technology, devices, and media'. i just wanna know what the RIAA has done. if there's more piracy, then surely there must be more response by the RIAA

Comment: Please re-open this question that was closed as opinion-based or unclear. I changed the secondary opinion question into what it was intended to be: some elaboration of the primary [factual](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/54809/785) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Recent RIAA activity

**Action based on May 2020 [US Copyright Office report](https://www.copyright.gov/policy/section512/section-512-full-report.pdf)**

[Hollywood and tech prep for another round of copyright wars](https://www.axios.com/hollywood-and-tech-prep-for-another-round-of-copyright-wars-eade52f1-9d37-485e-9fc9-b3e497a7ce3a.html)

> RIAA and other music industry groups, including the Music Artists Coalition and the National Music Publishers Association, have outlined three key concessions they want from tech platforms they say would address issues identified in the report: ...
>
> - Help cracking down on stream ripping. ...
> - Better monitoring for infringements. ...
> - Reducing repeat notices. ...

**RIAA action in relation to Twitch**

[Musicians Criticize Jeff Bezos' 'Willful Blindness' to Twitch Music Royalties](https://www.billboard.com/articles/business/9431760/jeff-bezos-twitch-music-royalties-artist-rights-alliance-letter)

> In June, the RIAA filed 2,500 copyright takedown notices to Twitch users, just as policymakers were debating the DMCA's efficacy in Congress, seemingly in a move to add pressure to Twitch on the licensing front.

[Social Media's Latest Copyright Crackdown](https://www.forbes.com/sites/petersuciu/2020/07/14/social-medias-latest-copyright-crackdown/#682d7a091da9)

> Last month [i.e., June] Twitch users began to get "takedown notices" for the first time, music trade magazine Billboard reported. The notices, which reportedly came out of the blue, listed the claimant as the Recording Industry Association of America (RIAA), and the infringing material was mostly recorded clips of old live broadcasts.

**RIAA statements/action regarding COVID-19 relief programs**

[RIAA Statement on Senate Passage of COVID-19 Stimulus Bill](https://www.riaa.com/riaa-statement-on-senate-passage-of-covid-19-stimulus-bill/)

> Mitch Glazier, Chairman and CEO of the Recording Industry Association of America (RIAA), released the following statement today on Senate passage of the Phase III stimulus package to address the devastating economic impact of the COVID-19 pandemic.

[An Exhaustive Guide to Coronavirus-Relief Resources for the Music Community](https://variety.com/2020/music/news/coronavirus-covid-19-relief-music-community-resource-guide-help-1203551535/)

> The most exhaustive list of resources for the music community that Variety has seen have been posted by A2IM (the American Association of Independent Music), the trade organization for the independent-music community, and a joint effort from the RIAA, SONA, NSAI, NMPA, the Recording Academy, MAC, A2IM, ASCAP and BMI.

**General activity related to rights**

[RIAA Says SoundExchange Is Authoritative Source for ISRC Data in the U.S.](https://www.billboard.com/articles/business/9422520/riaa-soundexchange-isrc-data-source)

> SoundExchange has been designated by the Recording Industry Association of America as the authoritative source for International Standard Recording Code (ISRC) data in the United States. ... ISRC is used throughout the music industry to maintain efficiency across supply chains, reporting, music discovery, archiving and rights management.